# Mercurial mark as resolvedn (resolve -m) is not working

Tags: mercurial, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a Netbeans property file that had a conflict. I removed the conflict manually and attempted to resolve it using resolve -m, but mercurial does not seem to accept this mark:

```
$ hg resolve -m RESTServices/nbproject/project.properties
$ hg resolve --list
U RESTServices/nbproject/project.properties
R RESTServices/web/main.js
R RESTServices/web/summer_api/renderable_alpha/PlatonicRenderable.js
$ hg commit -m "resolved"
abort: unresolved merge conflicts (see hg help resolve)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks , K

Comment: `ls -la RESTServices/nbproject/project.properties`? Does this exact path exist?

Comment: Yes... well I restarted my computer (a Mac) and it now works. Weird.

Comment: Perhaps having Netbeans open was the problem..